# How to open two Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I use the following splitview for my mobile application.

[asyraf splitview](http://asyraf9.github.com/jquerymobile-splitview/)

For example my first left content in the tablet view is a button. when I click the button it loads a new page with a second button and a back button to the first page. When I click on the second button it loads a right content. 
When I click the back button it loads the first page left content but the right content is the same.
How can I on click the back button load a new left content and a new right content at the same time?

**Attention:** The right content call need a `href="rightPage"` and `data-panel="main"`

Answer (score 1):

Attach the following to the button's click() event:

```
location.hash = "pagehash";
```

Comment: Hi it work's in splitview on a tablet but not on simple view on a smartphone. I tried this: `function setBlankPage(){

       
       location.hash="#rightPage";
       
       
       
      }` and    this in html: `<a data-rel="back" onclick="setBlankPage()"   data-role="button"  data-transition="none" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="arrow-l">home</a>`

Comment: Are you using different browsers on the different devices?

Comment: No I use it as an android app. I start it with phonegap. I load the html file like this: `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");`

Comment: That might be the issue.. Try and install a `localhost` server like XAMPP / MAMP. The `file://` domain causes issues with particular things. Otherwise, you could just try it on a real server. ;)